# Name Ranged = value of 2 named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I got a Named range in Column A that is the length of the named range in Column B/C (query result)

Now i want Column A to have the information of both Column B and Column C separated by " - "

Range1 = `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(Constances!$B:$B),1)`

Range2 = `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(Constances!$B:$B),1)`

Range3 =  `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(Constances!$C:$C),1)`

What i was thinking off is = `Range1=Range2&"- "&Range3`

Anyway to fix this in Excel so it happens automatically every time the Sheet starts? Or Alternatively, can this be solved using VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, the code will run whenever the file is opened. The code needs to go in the ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Range("Range1").Value = Evaluate("=Range2 & ""-"" & Range3")


With Sheets("Constances")
    With .Range("B1", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1)
        .Clear
        .Formula = "= B1 & ""-"" & C1"
        .Value = .Value 'this removes formulae
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Discovered one problem, 
for some reason range1 goes further then range2/3 and fills in a series of #N/A
And in a other instance it does not reach the full range and gives #N/A
 instead of the actual value.

Comment: Range1 is defined on the size of Range2. If Range2 changes then so will Range1. You might want to add a line to clear column A before adding the formula in case Range2 has shrunk.

Comment: Also the code only runs when the file is opened so you might want to reconsider that.

Comment: @SRJ

Added it to a button. 

First i let columns B and C be filled by the query, in Excel i check the range of Range1 and it goes tot he same row as Columbs B and C. 

I press the button with the code you gave me and the range becomes something else. (sometimes smaller sometimes larger then the range should be)

Comment: As far as I can see I've answered your question and I can't replicate your problem so I assume it has something to do with your data query. I have added another formulation above which does not rely on your named ranges.

Comment: when i manually do the formula in Excel with the same dataset it does work.
So the dataset doesn't seem to be the problem. The data comes out correct, when i select the range the correct range is given as well. But i gave up on this bit for now, was only meant to make a small part a bit more user friendly.  (being able to see the item and description) but seeing the item alone should be more then enough.